# Why the product of measure is a tensor product?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ two measure. What is the justification to say that the measure product is a tensor product ? i.e. why $\mu\times \nu$ is written $\mu\otimes \nu$ ? (Of course, beside the fact that is by definition or it's just a notation). Our teacher told us that the reason that we write it as a tensor product it's because it behave as a tensor product). But I don't understand this (I'm not very confortable with tensor product).

Comment: For example, assuming $\sigma$-finiteness, $L^1(\mu\otimes\nu)=L^1(\mu)\otimes L^1(\nu)$ as Banach spaces.

Comment: I put on bounty on it because I would be interested by then answer as well. Regarding @user10354138 comment, what is $L^1(\mu)\otimes L^1(\nu)$ and why is it isomorphic to $L^1(\mu\otimes \nu)$ ?

Comment: @user10354138 I have no idea why $L^1(\mu\otimes \nu) = L^(\mu)\otimes L^1(\nu)$. I might think it's false. Can you explain why you think it's true?

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, this should simply be called the product of the two measurable spaces. In fact, it satisfies the corresponding universal property (When the category treated is the category of measure spaces $(X,\mu)$ with the natural morphisms.

However, a different way of viewing the operations is to think of our category as a monoidal category, where the binary operation is $(X,\mu)\otimes(Y,\nu)\rightarrow(X\times Y,\mu\otimes \nu)$, Every category with a product operation has a monoidal structure and in the case of vector spaces, that operation is the tensor product.

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ is a real-valued function of the variable $x\in X$, and $g$ is a function of $y\in Y$, then the function of two variables 
$$
(x, y)\in X\times Y \mapsto f(x)g(y)$$
is called *tensor product* of $f$ and $g$ and denoted by $f\otimes g$. The tensor product of measures extends this definition; indeed, if $\mu$ and $\nu$ have densities $f$ and $g$ respectively, then 
$$
\mu\otimes \nu = f\otimes g\, dxdy.$$
(Here, of course, $x$ and $y$ are interpreted as real variables.)

Comment: Of, but The tensor product as vector space is really different... So at the end, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: It is not so different; it a **special case** of a more general construction. Indeed, there is an abstract theory of tensor products, which can become very abstract. But the simple construction I outlined here is one of the concrete realizations of the tensor product, in the case in which the spaces are spaces of functions. In all the applications I have ever seen, the tensor product ends up being the one of this answer; this includes differential geometry, linear algebra, and measure theory.

Answer (score 4):

For every measure space $(\Omega, \Sigma, m)$ and every $f=f(\omega) \in L^1(\Omega, \Sigma, m)$, let's define $m(f(\omega))$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
m(f(\omega)):=\int_{\Omega}f(\omega)dm(\omega).
\end{equation}
If $f_1(x),f_2(x),\dots f_n(x)\in L^1(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and $g_1(y), g_2(y), \dots g_n(y) \in L^1(Y,\Sigma_2,\nu)$, then:
\begin{align}
(\mu \otimes \nu) \Big(\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)g_k(y)\Big)
&= \sum_{k=1}^n (\mu \otimes \nu) ( f_k(x)g_k(y))\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n  \mu(f_k(x)) \nu(g_k(y))
\end{align}
where the latter equality is true thanks to Fubini's theorem.

If you look at the construction of the tensor product of linear mappings and compare it with these equations, you can see they share the same pattern.