# On the definition of tensor product measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, tensor-products, mathematical-physics

I have come across the term "tensor product measures", especially in the context of mathematical physics, and I am unclear on what exactly they are. I tried looking up some definitions online but I could not find anything concrete.

Based on [Why the product of measure is a tensor product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2996606/why-the-product-of-measure-is-a-tensor-product), there seems to be a relationship between the tensor product measure and product measures. However, the replies in that post have left me with more questions than answers.

Can anyone define what exactly a tensor product measure is, how is it related to the standard product measure, and why is it an object of interest?

Comment: The linked question is rather about *notation*: for the (standard) product of measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ we use $\mu\otimes\nu$ to denote the product measure. I'm not aware of anything like 'tensor product of measures'.

Comment: @Berci why not tensor some measures?  After all for a given measurable space, the collection of finite signed measures forms a Banach space.  From here you should be able to tensor away no?

Comment: See also these notes: http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~labutin/real_analysis_Fubini.pdf